# Android SQLiteDatabase table does not exists

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having a class named GameDb and it's extending SQLiteOpenHelper. I don't know why, but onCreate it's not called, the table is not created !

Having a singelton for all my activities and fragments:

```
public MyApp extends Application
{
   // .... Code

   private GameDb gameDb;

   public GameDb getGameDb()
   {
      if (gameDb == null)
         gameDb = new GameDb(this);

      return this.gameDb;
   }
}
```

Getting all games from database, calling from an activity

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
      // Code....

      // Get all games
      ArrayList<Game> allGames = getMyApp().getGameDb().getAllGames();
   }
}
```

Class which contains all necessary methods for querying the database (writing and reading). This methods are not written below because it's not necessary.

```
public class GameDb
{
   private SQLiteDatabase db;
   private GameDbHelper dbHelper;

   public GameDb(Context context)
   {
      this.dbHelper = new GameDbHelper(context);
      this.db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public ArrayList<Games> getAllGames()
   {
       // return db.query(....);
   }

   public void insertNewGame(int id, String name)
   {
      // db.query(....);
   }

   // Static inner class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper
   private static class GameDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
   {
      public GameDbHelper(Context context)
      {
         super(context, "DB_NAME", null, 1);
      }

      // On create not called !
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
      {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE my_table(_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, date TEXT);");
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
      {
         dropTable(db);
         onCreate(db);
      }

      public void dropTable(SQLiteDatabase db)
      {
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table");
      }
   }     
}
```

When I'm trying to get all games, or add a new game I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION, (1) no such table: my_table

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app so any possible old database file is deleted.

Comment: or simply increment the db version when creating it.

Comment: @njzk2 True, though I've found that for beginners with this kind of problems the uninstall/clear data way is the most straightforward during development. No need to exercise `onUpgrade()` code paths yet and keeps the code simpler by not having to go to arbitrarily large version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a old database present on your device and database doesn't always get deleted when you reinstall the app using IDE. Thus you must uninstall the app manually and the reinstall your app using IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe onCreate() gets implicitly called when you instantiate your database object.  You need to explicitly call your Activity's openOrCreateDatabase() method.